# I am not able to Install ejabberd on Cent OS6

Tags: centos, xmpp, ejabberd

As seen in many tutorials and blogs, I've installed the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux).
I checked whether EPEL was enabled in my CentOS 6.
After I tried with the command

```
sudo yum install ejabberd    
No Package ejabberd available 
Error: nothing to do.
```

This is what happens every time I try to install it. I tried downloading the package directly by using a Lynx browser and tried to run using the command

```
rpm -Uvh ejabberd-16.09-0.x86_64.rpm.gz
```

It still says: `It is not an rpm package`

I am using CentOS 6 from a VPS at GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

-Download the package directly from the process one website.

-Get the download link copy it to clipboard and use

```
wget https://www.process-one.net/downloads/ejabberd/16.09/ejabberd-16.09-0.x86_64.rpm
```

This will download the ejabberd rpm package file.
Then use this to install ejabberd.

```
rpm -Uvh ejabberd-16.09-0.x86_64.rpm
```

Check if it is succesfully installed using

```
yum info ejabberd
```

It will give the ejabberd version details if not install it again properly.